# Check if already a user then insert into the database php

Tags: php, mysqli, registration

My code works, if I wish to insert into the database, but my checking whether the user already exists doesn't work.

*I thought the idea was to check if a row exists already with that username, if so don't add that user to the database, else

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password= password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
$username= $_POST['username'];

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$row_count = $result->num_rows;
if($row_count == 1){
    echo'User exists';
}else{
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
$statement->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);

if($statement->execute()){
     print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
}else{
     die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}
$statement->close();
}
```

Comment: You could just put a `UNIQUE` index on `users.username` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean, each username is alongside a user_Id pk if thats what you mean

Comment: If you add a `UNIQUE` index to `users.username` you don't really need to check to see if it exists first, you can just attempt to do the `INSERT` - generally it will fail with an error if you're attempting to insert data with an already existing unique key... however, you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax to update the existing record rather than attempt to create a new one, see : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Works perfectly, is there a way to output "User already exists" rather than a message saying duplicate key?

Comment: Also if you'd like to answer the question I can accept it

Comment: if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {
    print 'no way!';
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed the `Procedural style` &  `Object oriented style` for executing the query.

When using,

**1) Procedural Style**

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "Your Query");
```

use this, `$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

**2)Object oriented style**

```
$result = $mysqli->query("Your Query");
```

Use this, `$row_count = $result->num_rows;`

So, According to your code, You are using Object Oriented Style. So, you need to change

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

to

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

**Edited Code.**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password= password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
$username= $_POST['username'];

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$row_count = $result->num_rows;
if($row_count == 1)
{
    echo 'User exists';
}
else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    //bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
    $statement->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);

    if($statement->execute())
    {
         print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
    }
    else
    {
         die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
    }
    $statement->close();
}
```

For more info, check this [mysqli_num_rows vs ->num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = ("SELECT username FROM userlist WHERE username='$username'");
$query = $conn->query($db);
if(mysqli_fetch_array($query) > 0 ) { //check if there is already an entry for that username
    echo "Username already exists!";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)