# How to separately check if PHP username or email exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Right now my code checks if both the username and email variables exist in the database because they are both unique keys, but how do I make it so I can check each one individually and output different responses?

Such as if the username exists -> "That username already exists."
Or if the email exists, but username does not -> "That email already exists."

```
<?php
  include 'include/connection.php';

  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['password']);
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['name']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['email']);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (username, password, name, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$name', '$email')";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Your account was created successfully, please login to continue.";
    echo '<form action="login.php">
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
          </form>';
  } else {
    echo "That username already exists, please try again.";
    echo '<form action="registration.php">
            <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />
          </form>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Here is full explanation  click here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129791/check-if-already-a-user-then-insert-into-the-database-php

Comment: @Kheteshkumawat So I should check to see if the username or email exists before I attempt to insert it into the database?

Comment: I commented link to full explanation this answer first you select query run than check duplicate entries email and user name.

Comment: Is thing code going to be put inside a live environment? It's not completely safe.

Comment: I rolled the question back to a previous revision. You can post your own answer instead or delete question. Please don't deface the original post.

Comment: It’s not a production environment.  It’s just for a school project. I didn’t know where to post the solution I came up with since it was a combination from different responses.

Comment: @ChaCol You need to accept the answer and upvote, which solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way of having a function and write SQL to check for `email` and `username` both.

```
SELECT username, email from userdata where username = ? OR email = ?
```

And, loop through the resultset and check if `email` or `username` exists and return error message accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
 $checkUserNameSql = "Select Count(username) as username from userdata WHERE username = '".$username."'";

$result=mysql_query($checkUserNameSql);
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $data['username'];
```

If you get a count you can apply your check on that.

Comment: `$result_username = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM userdata WHERE username = $username");`

`$username_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_username);`

`} else if ($username_count == 1) {` I tried something like this but it says "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result"

Comment: Your SELECT Query is worng.

`"SELECT username FROM userdate WHERE  username = '.$username.'" `

Comment: I fixed that, but now it's completely ignoring my else if statement. If the username exists it skips to my else statement instead of going to my `} else if ($count_username == 1) {`

Comment: How many rows are you getting in `$count_username` have you checked that?

Comment: I got it working. I had to switch it from what you had ".$username." to just "$username"

Comment: Great!! Please up-vote my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: why should they upvote the answer? They're using the mysqli_ api and you gave an answer with mysql_. Those different apis are not compatible together. You need to edit your answer so that it's compatible with mysqli_. Plus, it doesn't  address the question. I question the upvote for it also.

Answer (score -2):

Used below code. first you need to check username and email then insert the record.

```
include 'include/connection.php';
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['password']);
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['name']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['email']); 

  $checkUser    = 'select  email ,username from userdata where email="'.$email.'" or username = "'.$username.'"';
  $result       = mysqli_query($conn,$checkUser);
  $row          = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  if(!empty($row)){
    if($row['email']==$email){
        echo "That email already exists. Please try again";
    }
    else if($row['username']==$username){
        echo "That username already exists. Please try again";
    }

    echo '<form action="registration.php">
        <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />
      </form>';
  }
  else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (username, password, name, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$name', '$email')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Your account was created successfully, please login to continue.";
    echo '<form action="login.php">
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
          </form>';
     }
  }
```